# Problem with sample_n(2, replace=F) in a list of data with some data's size less than 2

Tags: r, dplyr, sampling

I need help with sample_n() in ‘dplyr’ in R:
I have a list of data `riskset[[1]], riskset[[2]],..., riskset[[1000]])`, each element `riskset[[i]]` of the list is a data frame of observations, and I divided the observations in each `riskset` into group 1:4 based on the distribution of a variable. So the data in `riskset[[i]]` looks like this:

```
id      sex        grp      ...
1        F          1       ...
2        M          3       ...
3        F          1       ...
4        M          4       ...
5        F          2       ...
6        F          3       ...
......................
```

I want to sample 2 observations from each grp within each riskset and save them as a list of sample. I used
`sample<- list()`

```
for(i in 1:1000){
sample[[i]] <- riskset[[i]] %>% group_by(grp) %>% sample_n(2,replace=F)
}
```

It gave me error:

```
size must be less or equal than 1 (size of data), set ‘replace = TRUE’ to use sampling with replacement.
```

I tried the code on the riskset which has more than 2 obs in each grp, it worked. But it doesn’t work on the riskset which has less than 2 obs in some group. For the group that has less than 2 obs, I want all the obs it has. And for the group that has more than 2 obs, I want to sample 2 obs without replacement. How can I achieve my sampling goal using R functions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

We can use `map` to loop over the `list` ('riskset'), then grouped by 'grp', apply the `sample_n`

```
library(tidyerse)
out <- map(riskset, ~ .x  %>%
                    group_by(grp) %>%
                    sample_n(pmin(n(), 2), replace = TRUE))
```

Or another option is `slice`

```
map(riskset, ~ .x %>%
                  group_by(grp) %>%
                  slice(if(n() < 2) 1 else sample(row_number(), 2))
```

Or without using `if/else`

```
map(riskset, ~ .x %>%
                  group_by(grp) %>%
                  slice(sample(seq_len(pmin(n(), 2)))))
```

#### data

```
iris1 <-  iris %>%
               select(grp = Species, everything()) %>%
               slice(c(1:5, 51))
riskset <- list(iris1, iris1)
```